# Setter not launching when submiting form

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm having a bit of a struggle with Spring and Thymeleaf
I have a controller like this

```
@Autowired user user;
@Autowired entry entrycount;

@GetMapping("/blog")
public String blog1(Model model, HttpSession session){
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("entry", entrycount); 
    System.out.println("GET METHOD");  
    return "blogform";
}

@PostMapping("/blog")
public String blog(Model model, HttpSession session){
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    user.insertentry();
    System.out.println("POST METHOD");  
    model.addAttribute("entry", entrycount);
    entrycount.inc();

    return "blogform";
}
```

with form like this:

```
<form method = "post" th:object="${user}">
            <label><h1>Hello User!</h1></label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{newEntry}">
            <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And when I hit Submit button, user.newEntry doesn't set

When I make this

```
public String blog1(Model model, HttpSession session, user user, entry entrycount){...}
```

program sets the value, but each time I submit form, I get new object

```
//User.java
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class user {
    public List<String> userentries = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String newEntry;
    public void setnewEntry(String i){
        System.out.println("SETTER METHOD i = " + i);  
        newEntry = i;        
    }
   
    public String getnewEntry(){
        System.out.println("GETTER METHOD");  
        return newEntry;
    }

    public void insertentry(){
        userentries.add(newEntry);
        System.out.println("INSERT METHOD");  
        for (String string : userentries) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

[Setter not launching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOoJp.png)
[Setter launching with objects added to mapping methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YDol.png)

-----------------------EDIT------------------------

Okay, I had to implement new class like "EntryReceiver" and send the form result to it.

Later just this:

```
@RequestMapping("/blog")
    public String blog( HttpSession session, final Model model, EntryReceiver ER){
        model.addAttribute("EntryReceiver", new EntryReceiver());

        entryCount.inc();
        model.addAttribute("entryCount", entryCount.getEntry());

        user.setNewEntry(ER.getEntry());
        user.insertentry();
        model.addAttribute("userentries", user.getUserEntries());
                
        return "blogform";
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you are making things very complex. Maybe read about [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had to implement new class like "EntryReceiver" and send the form result to it.

Later just this:

```
@RequestMapping("/blog")
    public String blog( HttpSession session, final Model model, EntryReceiver ER){
        model.addAttribute("EntryReceiver", new EntryReceiver());

        entryCount.inc();
        model.addAttribute("entryCount", entryCount.getEntry());

        user.setNewEntry(ER.getEntry());
        user.insertentry();
        model.addAttribute("userentries", user.getUserEntries());
                
        return "blogform";
    }
```